# mini cart pushes the header down, pulls wrong item render sidebar/default.phtml, instead of mini-cartpro/default.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.8, sidebar, mini-cart

So The theme has a mini cart feature... It works, and updates the cart via ajax on addItem and remove item. When your NOT logged in, the feature works exactly how I want. The user add a product to the cart , the cart updates with out refreshing the page. When your logged in, when you add something to the cart, it uses the sidebar/default.phtml to show the updated mini cart, ( image with the header pushed down) refresh the page , and it shows as expected. I can not figure out what is telling mini-cart.phtml to use sidebar/default.phtml as the item renderer.

[image: What I want]
[image: Not what I want]
So The theme has a mini cart feature... It works, and updates the cart via ajax on addItem and remove item. When your NOT logged in, the feature works exactly how I want. The user add a product to the cart , the cart updates with out refreshing the page. When your logged in, when you add something to the cart, it uses the sidebar/default.phtml to show the updated mini cart, ( image with the header pushed down) refresh the page , and it shows as expected. I can not figure out what is telling mini-cart.phtml to use sidebar/default.phtml as the item renderer.

cartpro.xml

```
<reference name="header">
        <block type="cartpro/cart_cartpro" name="mini-cartpro" as="mini-cartpro" template="sm/cartpro/checkout/cart/mini-cartpro.phtml">
            <action method="setData"><name>template_item_renderer</name><value>sm/cartpro/checkout/cart/mini-cartpro/default.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="setData"><name>product_image_width</name><value>80</value></action>
            <action method="setData"><name>product_image_height</name><value>80</value></action>
            <action method="createSessionDataByName"><session_name>minicart</session_name></action>
        </block>



    </reference>



</default>

<customer_account translate="label">
    <remove name="cart_sidebar"/>
     <reference name="left"> 
        <block type="cartpro/cart_cartpro" name="cart_sidebar_clone" template="sm/cartpro/checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-"> 
            <action method="setData"><name>template_item_renderer</name><value>sm/cartpro/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="setData"><name>product_image_width</name><value>50</value></action> 
            <action method="setData"><name>product_image_height</name><value>50</value></action> 
            <action method="createSessionDataByName"><session_name>sidebar</session_name></action>   
        </block>             
    </reference>
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated , this is my first question, Im sure I did things all kinds of wrong , I will reformat or update anything that does not meet question standards. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ajax call was requesting the wrong template. All is good now